# My wordpress website shows the slideshow in http mode and it is not showing in https mode

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, slideshow

In the webiste [http://www.gulfmech.com/](http://www.gulfmech.com) I'm able to see the image slideshow in `http` mode.

Recently I activated the SSL certificate for the website. Now the issue is that I'm not able to see the slideshow in the `https` mode.

After following so many forums I changed the Site Address (URL) and wordpress Url in wordpress admin settings to https://www.gulfmech.com/ and  I tried uninstalling the meteor slideshow plugin which is used in the website and installed it again. But nothing seems to make the slider work in `Https` mode.

Someone please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to jQuery not being loaded in correctly.

If you look at the console log in the browser when loading the website in `http` mode and `https` mode, you will see that there are loads of jQuery errors occuring in the `https` mode.

The browser won't load in the `http` version of jQuery because the connection is meant to be secure which it isn't between your website and jQuery.

What you will want to load in instead is the code below.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This means that the connection type will be figured out by the browser and it will get the correct version.